# How to drag and drop files to a (places|launcher) gnome applet

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, drag-and-drop, applet

I made a shortcut to my home folder by dragging and dropping it to the panel.

Is there a way that I can drag and drop files to that applet in order to save the file in the folder location?

What I really want is to make a shortcut to one of my Ubuntu One folders, that when I drag and drop a file, selected text or url to that applet, it saved the dropped 'element' in the folder for synchronization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using ubuntu, I hope you are using 11.04 with Unity because there is a launcher with this capability!

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/drag-and-drop-ubuntuone-file-uploader-for-the-ubuntu-unity-launcher/

Comment: Also, Ubuntu One just upgraded the free storage to 5Gb!